# Adding record to sql with gridview rowcommand buttonfield

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to add a **Register** button to every row in my course `gridview` so that when the user click on the register button on that particular row, it will register him to that particular course on that row by adding a course registration record into sql.

How should I write my code to insert that row's data into sql?

C#:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Register")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
    }
```

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" Width="394px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SpeakerName" HeaderText="Speaker" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="startdate" HeaderText="Date" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Capacity" HeaderText="Capacity" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Button" ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="RegButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Register"
                        CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" Text="Register" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Select" SelectText="Details" ShowSelectButton="True" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You got the row now get the data from the row and save it to the database. Whats the problem ?

Comment: How should write to add the data from the row to sql db?

Comment: You need to read tutorial to get the data from gridview row , and then do the database connection and then fire the query to save the data.

Comment: @CoderofCode have same problem, can you help me out sir?

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod Add question on stack with details and you will get the answer. Without details its harad to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

first you should add course `Id` (primary key) as `datakeynames property` to `GridView1`,and then can get the `Id` on `GridView1_RowCommand` like below :

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Register")
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
        int courseId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
        //your other codes
    }
```

so,you have your course `Id` and by selecting the record you can add current record to sql.hope it helps.

Edit :

also you don't need this part `CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"` in your aspx page any more